# Firestore rule not working as expected, user still able to access other user's data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an Android app that requires user to sign in with Firebase Authentication. They can make appointment and display their appointment made using the app.

[image: This is how the appointments made are stored]
This is how the appointments made are stored.

[image: Firestore rules]
This is how my rules look like. I followed the documentation from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure)
However, after testing I found that User A is still seeing appointments made by User B. Can anyone take a look and tell me what's wrong with my rules?

Comment: remove the `/users/{userId}` part.

Comment: @RonRoyston but if I did that wouldn't the "== userId" part become undefined? Btw I tried your suggestion and I'm still able to see appointments made by the other user so no dice.

Comment: I'm thinking about putting /appointments under /users/{userId}/appointments instead. Can I do this and is this a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

For Firestore use `resource.data.owner`

```
match /processing/{order} {
  allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
}
```